# How to split the value into 2 values

Tags: c#, vb.net

User Entry like this

```
textbox1.text = 01/02/03/......
```

I want to display the values separately in 3 textbox like this

After `"/"` it should move to next row

```
txt1.text =  01
    txt2.text = 02
   txt3.text =  03
    ....
```

How to do this.

Need Vb.net code help

Comment: retagging to include c# code for future reference becouse it's a common question, what do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

If it's always 3 text boxes, you could just write static code for each text box, like this:

```vb
'EDIT: This code now checks for the existence of a second or third value to avoid
'out of bounds errors
Dim originalValue As String = "01/02/03"
Dim splitBySlash As String() = originalValue.Split("/")

txt1.Text = splitBySlash(0)
If splitBySlash.Length > 1 Then txt2.Text = splitBySlash(1)
If splitBySlash.Length > 2 Then txt3.Text = splitBySlash(2)
```

**Option 2**

If you have a variable number of text boxes based on the slashes, you'll have to create them at run time and add them to the parent control, like this:

```vb
'You can enter as many (or few) slashes as you like in this code, it will automatically
'adjust the text boxes created as necessary.
Dim originalValue As String = "01/02/03" 'could go on like /04/05/etc
Dim splitBySlash As String() = originalValue.Split("/")

For Each value As String In splitBySlash
    Dim newTxt As New TextBox()
    newTxt.Text = value

    yourParentControl.Controls.Add(newTxt)
Next
```

Comment: dude, thanks for your help, but user can enter 01/02 or 01 also, in that case, it is showing error as out of index in "splitBysplash".  help me...

Comment: Use the second version of the code?  In the first, a user must enter *exactly* three values or it will crash, in the second, they can enter as many as they want (I have edited the answer to reflect this).

Comment: i have constant textbox, i dont want to create at run time, instead of that adding at run time, i can get the array count, then i can pass the value to textbox, can u help me...

Comment: I've added code to verify the array bounds in Option 1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string rockString =  "01/02/03/";
string[] words = rockString.Split('/');
foreach (string word in words)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(word);
     }
```

**As you ask in the comment**

In different textbox

```
textbox1.text = words[0]; //textbox1.text="01";
    textbox2.text = words[2]; //textbox2.text="02";
    textbox3.text = words[3]; //textbox3.text="03";
```

In the same textbox

```
 textbox1.text = words[0]+words[1]+words[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) or Regex.Split

```
Dim value As String = "01//02//03//" 
Dim lines As String() = Regex.Split(value, "//") 
For Each line As String In lines    
Console.WriteLine(line) 
Next
```